# jQuery - Child-row td below th rather than on the left (aligning)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a separate sub table to appear directly below that row. I was able to do this; however, I am having hard time aligning the header and data of that sub table. My header is in the same row as my sub table data; I want them in a different row where the header is above the data (td).
For example:

> **Description**  **Arrival**
>   
> Heavy

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong when I am appending the sub table headers?

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="parentTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="category">
      <th>Unique ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="parentTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr1 = generateItem();
  if (arr1) {
    var arr2 = [].concat(arr1);
    var tr;
    $.each(arr2, function(i, e) {
      tr = $('<tr>');
      //TODO only add <a> tag if there is going to be a child row!
      tr.append("<td>" + "<a href='#'>" + (e.UniqueId || "") + "</a>" + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Name || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Email || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Price || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Hours || "") + "</td>");
      $('#parentTableBody').append(tr);

        tr = $('<tr class="child-row">');
                 tr.append("<th>" + "Description" + "</th>");
             tr.append("<th>" + "Arrival" + "</th>");
             tr.append("<td>" + (e.Description || "") + "</td>");
             tr.append("<td>" + (e.Arrival || "") + "</td>");
             $('#parentTableBody').append(tr);  
             tr.hide();

    });

  }
});

function generateItem() {
  var item = [{
      UniqueId: "0",
      Name: "Alex",
      Email: "alex@email.com",
      Price: "$20.00",
      Hours: "1",
      Description: "N/A",
      Arrival: "Noon"
    },
    {
      UniqueId: "1",
      Name: "Jay",
      Email: "jay@email.com",
      Price: "$12.00",
      Hours: "0.2",
      Description: "Small",
      Arrival: "test"
    },
    {
      UniqueId: "2",
      Name: "Dylan",
      Email: "dylan@email.com",
      Price: "$32.00",
      Hours: "2.2",
      Description: "Heavy"
    }
  ];

  return item;
}

$(function() {
  $('#parentTable tbody a').on("click", function(event) {
      $baseRow = $(event.target).closest("tr");
      next = $baseRow.next("tr");
      if (next.is(".child-row")){
        next.toggle();
      }

  });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/36SRa/328/)

Comment: Do you mean [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/36SRa/331/)?

Comment: Yes. But on start, I wanted to hide the sub-table (including the headers and data of the sub-table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best approachment using a child row that contains a child table in order to keep the html 5 validity.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr1 = generateItem();
  if (arr1) {
    var arr2 = [].concat(arr1);
    var tr;
    $.each(arr2, function(i, e) {
      tr = $('<tr>');
      //TODO only add <a> tag if there is going to be a child row!
      tr.append("<td>" + "<a href='#'>" + (e.UniqueId || "") + "</a>" + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Name || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Email || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Price || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Hours || "") + "</td>");
      $('#parentTableBody').append(tr);
      
      //TODO Subtable headers and data
        //subtable tr header
        containerRow = $('<tr class="child-row">');
        containerColumn = $('<td colspan="5">');
        subTable = $('<table class="child-table">');
        trHeader = $('<tr>');
        trHeader.append("<th>" + "Description" + "</th>");
        trHeader.append("<th>" + "Arrival" + "</th>");
        subTable.append(trHeader);
        //subtable tr data
        tr = $('<tr>');
        tr.append("<td>" + (e.Description || "") + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (e.Arrival || "") + "</td>");
        subTable.append(tr); 
        containerColumn.append(subTable);
        containerRow.append(containerColumn);
        $('#parentTableBody').append(containerRow); 
        
        containerRow.hide();
               
    });

  }
});

function generateItem() {
  var item = [{
      UniqueId: "0",
      Name: "Alex",
      Email: "alex@email.com",
      Price: "$20.00",
      Hours: "1",
      Description: "N/A",
      Arrival: "Noon"
    },
    {
      UniqueId: "1",
      Name: "Jay",
      Email: "jay@email.com",
      Price: "$12.00",
      Hours: "0.2",
      Description: "Small",
      Arrival: "test"
    },
    {
      UniqueId: "2",
      Name: "Dylan",
      Email: "dylan@email.com",
      Price: "$32.00",
      Hours: "2.2",
      Description: "Heavy"
    }
  ];

  return item;
}

$(function() {
  $('#parentTable tbody a').on("click", function(event) {
      $baseRow = $(event.target).closest("tr");
      next = $baseRow.next("tr");
      if (next.is(".child-row")){
        next.toggle();
      }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="parentTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="category">
      <th>Unique ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="parentTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ernesthm. Thank you for an improved solution; I really appreciate more of your time. I think this one works really great. I will apply it to my existing code. Thank you!

Comment: Just did. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can build an inner table instead of an inner row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr1 = generateItem();
  if (arr1) {
    var arr2 = [].concat(arr1);
    var tr;
    $.each(arr2, function(i, e) {
      tr = $('<tr>');
      //TODO only add <a> tag if there is going to be a child row!
      tr.append("<td>" + "<a href='#'>" + (e.UniqueId || "") + "</a>" + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Name || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Email || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Price || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Hours || "") + "</td>");
      $('#parentTableBody').append(tr);
      
      //TODO Subtable headers and data
        //subtable tr header
        subTable = $('<table class="child-table">');
        trHeader = $('<tr class="child-row">');
        trHeader.append("<th>" + "Description" + "</th>");
        trHeader.append("<th>" + "Arrival" + "</th>");
        subTable.append(trHeader);
        //subtable tr data
        tr = $('<tr class="child-row">');
        tr.append("<td>" + (e.Description || "") + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + (e.Arrival || "") + "</td>");
        subTable.append(tr); 
        $('#parentTableBody').append(subTable); 
        
        subTable.hide();
               
    });

  }
});

function generateItem() {
  var item = [{
      UniqueId: "0",
      Name: "Alex",
      Email: "alex@email.com",
      Price: "$20.00",
      Hours: "1",
      Description: "N/A",
      Arrival: "Noon"
    },
    {
      UniqueId: "1",
      Name: "Jay",
      Email: "jay@email.com",
      Price: "$12.00",
      Hours: "0.2",
      Description: "Small",
      Arrival: "test"
    },
    {
      UniqueId: "2",
      Name: "Dylan",
      Email: "dylan@email.com",
      Price: "$32.00",
      Hours: "2.2",
      Description: "Heavy"
    }
  ];

  return item;
}

$(function() {
  $('#parentTable tbody a').on("click", function(event) {
      $baseRow = $(event.target).closest("tr");
      next = $baseRow.next("table");
      if (next.is(".child-table")){
        next.toggle();
      }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="parentTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="category">
      <th>Unique ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="parentTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi ernesthm. Your solution worked. You're right, I should have created an entire new table rather than trying to fit a header below the row of the parent (inner row). Thank you, I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Hi Pray, you can see my other answer "Best approachment using a child row that contains a child table in order to keep the html 5 validity." I think is better than this one. Thanks.

Comment: Hey ernesthm. I am sorry for my late reply. I was going through the answers in order. I looked at your new solution, and I was going to model after that. Your improved answer works really great when I try to show the hidden child table! Thank you ernesthm!

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand what you are trying to do is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr1 = generateItem();
  if (arr1) {
    var arr2 = [].concat(arr1);
    var tr;
    $.each(arr2, function(i, e) {
      tr = $('<tr>');
      //TODO only add <a> tag if there is going to be a child row!
      tr.append("<td>" + "<a href='#'>" + (e.UniqueId || "") + "</a>" + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Name || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Email || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Price || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Hours || "") + "</td>");
      $('#parentTableBody').append(tr);

      //TODO Subtable headers and data
      tr = $('<tr class="child-row">');
      tr.append("<th>" + "Description" + "</th>");
      tr.append("<th>" + "Arrival" + "</th>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Description || "") + "</td>");
      tr.append("<td>" + (e.Arrival || "") + "</td>");
      $('#parentTableBody').append(tr);
      tr.hide();

    });

  }
});

function generateItem() {
  var item = [{
      UniqueId: "0",
      Name: "Alex",
      Email: "alex@email.com",
      Price: "$20.00",
      Hours: "1",
      Description: "N/A",
      Arrival: "Noon"
    },
    {
      UniqueId: "1",
      Name: "Jay",
      Email: "jay@email.com",
      Price: "$12.00",
      Hours: "0.2",
      Description: "Small",
      Arrival: "test"
    },
    {
      UniqueId: "2",
      Name: "Dylan",
      Email: "dylan@email.com",
      Price: "$32.00",
      Hours: "2.2",
      Description: "Heavy"
    }
  ];

  return item;
}

$(function() {
  $('#parentTable tbody a').on("click", function(event) {
    $baseRow = $(event.target).closest("tr");
    next = $baseRow.next("tr");
    if (next.is(".child-row")) {
      next.toggle();
    }

  });
});
```

```css
table th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="parentTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="category">
      <th>Unique ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Hours</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="parentTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey Ggprogamer, I am sorry if I wasn't clear. I wanted to format my hidden sub table like other answers like the one provided by ernesthm. Thank you for your time though.